# What is the value of a checkbox as an integer?

Tags: php

If i wanted to check the value of a checkbox, and input a 1 or ) to the database depending on what the user has checked, what would the value be that i'm checking?

```
if($checkbox == 1){

}else{

}
```

Comment: I'd say, check it out yourself. Run the form and `echo` the `$_POST` of `$_GET` you're getting. Part of learning to program is figuring stuff out yourself.

Comment: The request body from `form` always a `string`. If you want to check whether it's numeric or not, you can use function `is_numeric($_POST['checkbox'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the checkbox a value and then check for that! Like this:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['test']))
        echo $_POST['test'];  //Outout's the value of the checkbox here 'test'

    if (!empty($_POST['test']) && $_POST['test'] == "test")
        //do something

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value ="test">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually checkboxes have values.

```
<form action="checkbox.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="checked">Foo
  <input type="checkbox" name="bar" value="checked">Bar
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You can clearly see, that both checkboxes have a name and a value assigned to them. Your PHP variables will have these values if they're selected.

Then you can test for it in PHP:

```
if ($_GET['foo'] == 'checked') {
  // Do this
} else {
  // It's not checked. Do that
}
```

Comment: Little hint: turn error reporting on and you get a undefined!

Comment: @Rizier123: I didn't mean to provide the complete code, but a hint on how it works. I felt it's obvious to test whether the index is set beforehand.